# PL SQL CASE in Order By Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-order-by, case

I am trying to use CASE statement in the Order By Clause of SQL and I am getting the following error
Expected Char got NUMBER..
Expected Char got DATE..

```
(CASE when inp='PAPER' then 'PAPERSTOCK'
 when inp='DOCS' then 30
 when inp='DATE' then SYSDATE
 else 'NOTHING')
```

This is my problem.. I know CASE will return only one type of datatype.. I have a requirement where based on input Order By Clause should change.. the CASE statement should return DATE/NUMBER/VARCHAR..

Is this possible or do we haev any other option?

Comment: I added example data in question.. In reality they are not constants and are table columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu have three different data types being returned.  You have two options:  convert them to a compatible format (string) or use multiple case statements.

For the latter:

```
order by (CASE when inp = 'PAPER' then PAPERSTOCK end),
         (CASE when inp = 'DOCS' then DOCS end),
         (CASE when inp = 'DATE' then INPUTDATE end)
```

I changed the `then` values to refer to something like column names rather than constants.  If you are ordering by a constant, then it doesn't matter what the input is.